# Do we get a instanton $S^{3}$ if we do $1/n$ surgery on a knot in $S^{3}$?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, 3-manifolds, floer-homology

Consider the following question:
Let $K\subset S^{3}$ be a nontrivial knot, and let $Y$ be the manifold obtained by doing $1/n$-surgery ($n\geq1$). Is it possible that the instanton Floer homology of $Y$ vanishes?

The answer seems to be no. Indeed by  Gordon-Luecke's theorem, $Y$ is not $S^{3}$, while  as far as I know, people don't have any example of an integer homology 3-sphere other than $S^{3}$ having vanishing instanton Floer homology.

My question is: is there a rigorous proof of this statement? (for example, using instanton suture Floer homology?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kronheimer and Mrowka first proved that 1-surgery on a knot has non-trivial instanton Floer homology using Witten's conjecture (see their paper http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0311489).  They later proved this using sutured instanton Floer homology as you suggested (see Section 7 of http://arxiv.org/abs/0807.4891).

As far as I know, for $n$ at least 2, this is unknown in general.  K-M's first proof of Property P uses a long exact sequence in instanton Floer homology relating the instanton Floer homologies of $S^3$, $S^3_1(K)$, and $S^3_0(K)$.  Some total speculation would be to try to construct a long exact sequence relating the instanton Floer homologies of $S^3$, $S^3_{1/n}(K)$, and $S^3_0(K)$ with some sort of twisted coefficients (analogous to Theorem 9.14 in http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0105202) and try to repeat their argument.

Answer (score 6):

This follows now from [Theorem 1.15 of this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.13374) for $n>1$. To clarify, Theorem 1.15 is stated for framed instanton homology $I^\#(S^3_{1/n}(K))$. If instanton Floer homology $I(S^3_{1/n}(K))=0$, then by Definition 1 of [Froyshov](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-9383(01)00018-0), $\hat{I}(S^3_{1/n}(K))=0$ since it is a subquotient (notice I am not using Froyshov’s notation, see [section 9.1](https://doi.org/10.1112/jtopol/jtv012) for the relation between Scaduto’s and Froyshov’s notation).
Then by [Theorem 1.3](https://doi.org/10.1112/jtopol/jtv012) (which relates $\hat{I}$ and $I^\#$ for homology 3-spheres) $dim\ I^\#(S^3_{1/n}(K))=1$, and hence $S^3_{1/n}(K)$ is an instanton $L$-space ([Definition 1.13](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.13374)). Then [Theorem 1.15](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.13374) implies that $1/n \geq 2g-1$, a contradiction if $n >1$.

For $n=1$ (following Steven Sivek’s comment below), then $g=1$ by the above inequality. It is known that an $L$-space knot of genus 1 is the right-handed trefoil knot $T$ (see [Theorem 1.15 and Remark 1.7](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.13374)). Then $S^3_1(T)$ is the Poincaré homology 3-sphere (see [Proposition 7.12](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.13374)). But the Floer homology of the Poincaré homology 3-sphere is non-zero since (for example), the Euler characteristic is twice the [Casson invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casson_invariant?wprov=sfti1) which is $1$, as [proved originally by Floer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floer_homology#Instanton_Floer_homology) (even though it is an instanton homology $L$-space).

Comment: The condition is $\frac{1}{n} \geq 2g-1$, so you still have to deal with 1-surgery on the right-handed trefoil (i.e., the Poincaré homology sphere).  But this is known to have $I(Y) \neq 0$ anyway, so it's fine.  In general, the difference between $I(Y)$ and the reduced instanton homology $\hat{I}(Y)$ (which relates to $I^\#(Y)$ by the cited theorem 1.3) is measured by the Frøyshov invariant $h(Y)$, so in particular $I(Y)$ vanishes iff $\dim I^\#(Y)=1$ and $h(Y)=0$.

Comment: @StevenSivek: okay, thanks for the correction. I guess I mixed up the various $I$ notations and how they relate to Floer’s original invariant of homology 3-spheres. If you’d like to edit my answer with your corrections, I would be happy with that (or I can try to get to it some time). Although Tye’s answer was accepted (and is probably correct modulo someone carrying out his suggestion), I came across this question while googling and thought it might be useful to point out the progress in the literature since the time that the question was asked.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, if $C = \text{rank}(I_*(S^3_0(K)))$, we have $$f(k) = \text{rank}(I_*(S^3_{1/k}(K))) = kC.$$ This holds with any coefficient field.

Floer's exact sequence gives us an exact triangle relating $I_*(S^3_0) \to I_*(S^3_{1/k}) \to I_*(S^3_{1/(k+1)}).$ As a result, we have $f(k+1) \le f(k) + C$, and $f(1) = f(0) = C$.

But there's also the exact triangle of Culler, Daemi, and Xie, displayed as (1.4) [here](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/topo.12137), relating $I_*(S^3_{1/(k-1)}) \to I_*(S^3_{1/k})^2 \to I_*(S^3_{1/(k+1)})$. From this we have $2f(k) \le f(k-1) + f(k+1)$ for $k \ge 2$ (and for $k=1$ we get $f(2) = 2f(1)$).

Now $f(k) = kC$ can be proven by induction.

As a result, it follows that in Floer's triangle the connecting map $I_*(S^3_0) \to I_*(S^3_{1/k})$ is always zero, and in Culler-Daemi-Xie's triangle the connecting map $I_*(S^3_{1/(k+1)}) \to I_*(S^3_{1/(k-1)})$ is zero, as well.

At this point, if you know that the displayed maps in the CDX triangle above preserve the $\Bbb Z/2$-grading, you can argue by another induction using the CDX sequence that $I_*(S^3_{1/k}(K)) \cong I_*(S^3_1(K))^{\oplus k}$ as $\Bbb Z/2$-graded vector spaces.

Comment: This seems much more direct than my answer.

Comment: @IanAgol I think the fact that $I_*(S^3_{1/k}(K)) \cong I_*(S^3_0(K))^k$ as vector spaces might be fairly old, so that this was resolved in the Property P paper. But I can't find the claim in print.

Comment: The exact triangle of CDX is not proved in their paper (they work with admissible bundles, not ZHS^3), though they give a recipe that one can work out. Indeed, one (or a few) will.